# Tomcat HTTP Status 404

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a small web app and I had put all the compiled classes of it (Not jar/war but simple **.class** files of all the classes) in **/WEB-INF/classes/** folder of Tomcat. It was working fine without any issues.

Since I had to put/copy all the classes separately, I created a jar file of them using **Ant** and put that **app.jar** in **/WEB-INF/lib/** folder. I also moved all the individual **.class** files from **/WEB-INF/classes/** (to make sure they are not used by Tomcat). Then I restarted the Tomcat server and now I get HTTP STATUS 404.

Note that I left all the JSPs, web.xml etc as it was before. I just wanted to group all the **.class** files to a .jar to make my life easier.

Is there something else I need to do ?

Comment: You ought to stop this now and learn how to create and deploy a proper WAR file for your app.

Comment: [how-to-purge-tomcats-cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974882/how-to-purge-tomcats-cache-when-deploying-a-new-war-file-is-there-a-config-se) - though no accepted answer, but clear the cache too.