# Tomcat 404 no found , HttpSessionListener

Tags: tomcat

I've been trying some things in tomcat and suddenly got a status code 404 for all of my JSPs and Servlets.I am getting this error :

```
11-Jun-2018 17:40:57.528 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class [com.example.model.MySessionListener]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.model.MySessionListener
at .....

11-Jun-2018 17:40:57.528 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
```

I had a HttpSessionListener,but after this error occurred i've deleted , but the error is still there(after restarting and deleting log files).Why does the tomcat still ask for the HttpServletListener if i deleted it?How can i fix this?

Comment: Is probably mentioned in web.xml.

Comment: No,that's strange.I deleted it everywhere i could,classses,srcs,and web.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have made sure there are no references to com.example.model.MySessionListener, try performing a clean on the tomcat server to remove any possible references to the class. Also try removing and re adding the war file.

Comment: What do you mean by "clean"?How do i do that?

Comment: If you are using Tomcat in an IDE like eclipse, you can right click on your server (in the servers tab) and select "clean". You can also look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29273052/7101216 for steps via command line.